# I have a galaxy S3 and want to copy the data from my sdcard to my nexus 6 without a PC any ideas?

Tags: sync, hardware

My Asus laptop is caput and I would like to get the SD card data onto the nexus 6, any idea maybe direct cable between both phones?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender

Comment: I, personally, recommend [Shareit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps)

Answer (score 0):

You could try Airdroid which allows you to transfer files from your device to your laptop(and vice versa) via Wi-Fi and then transfer them to your Nexus.

Comment: OP doesn't want to use the PC.